# How to map a map of tuples into a tuple of maps in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, mapping

Having

```
val a: Map[String, (Int, Int)] = Map("a" -> (1, 10), "b" -> (2, 20))
```

what would be the right Scala way to derive

```
val b: (Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int]) = (Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2), Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20))
```

from `a`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
scala> val b = (a.mapValues(_._1), a.mapValues(_._2))
b: (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]) = (Map(a -> 1, b -> 2),Map(a -> 10, b -> 20))
```

Answer (score 6):

I like Sean's answer, but if you wanted, for some reason to traverse your map only once and didn't want to use Scalaz, here's another solution:

```
a.foldLeft((Map.empty[String, Int], Map.empty[String, Int])) {
  case ((a1, a2), (k, (v1, v2))) => (a1 + (k -> v1), a2 + (k -> v2))
}
```

Comment: Have you got an idea why have somebody downvoted your suggestion?

Comment: @Ivan No clue, really. Have I upset somebody?

Comment: @Ivan : I've tested the code - the result is exactly what you specified: `(scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]) = (Map(a -> 1, b -> 2),Map(a -> 10, b -> 20))`

Comment: I see, but maybe something conceptual or hidden we don't understand... Or maybe just a bad-mooded guy have wandered through... :-) Whatever, thank you for participating.

Comment: I'd like to know it as well. I promise to take any constructive criticism with dignity ;) Thanks Ivan for the follow up.

Answer (score 2):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val m = Map("a" -> (1, 10), "b" -> (2, 20))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,(Int, Int)] = Map(a -> (1,10), b -> (2,20))

scala> val (a, b) = m.toSeq foldMap { case (k, (v1, v2)) => (Map(k -> v1), Map(k -> v2)) }
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(b -> 2, a -> 1)
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(b -> 20, a -> 10)
```

Comment: Thank you too. @sean-parsons answer is definitely better readable, but I am going to try your way too to chack if it is more memory/cpu-efficient. And it is nice to know.

Comment: It certainly is more expensive. Much more object creation, and indirection. What Sean suggested is both more succinct and more performant.